# USB-C to USB-C Cable Recommendations for Pi 4

Tags: power, power-supply, usb-power, pi-4

Based on the USB-C implementation issue in Pi 4 rev. 1, I'm looking for recommendations on a non e-marked USB-C cable to use for power. Having dug through my own cable stash, I've found a couple of cables that meet this requirement, but nothing brand named that I can identify and purchase online.

The context for this request is a networking course I will be teaching beginning in January. Due to infrastructure constraints, it's not feasible to have all students relying on AC power, e.g., the RPi approved power supply. Based on past troubleshooting experience, I prefer to provide a list of approved power banks. I'm already anticipating that the USB-C factor is going to cause problems in the next iteration due to the incompatibility of e-marked cables.

In lieu of the Raspberry Pi Foundation offering a standalone USB-C cable option that is verified compatible with rev. 1, I'm hoping that StackExchange contributors can help me find a good online source!

Answer (score 1):

Before using a cable you must first notice these things first:
1. Never use a very long wired USB type-c cable
2. E marked or not you should use a cable that can sustain fast-charge
3. Always go for a good quality cable otherwise there will be losses in cable
4. Use a fresh set of cable and avoid using converters.
 Use an adapter with minimum 5V-2A. You must use the recommanded 3A adapter for networking course. The networking processes eats a lot of memory and needs a lot of processing speeds.